# What is the meaning of various honorific prefixes with "Sri"?

Tags: saint

We see many gurus, babas, saints with honorific titles such as

Sri Sri

108 Sri

1008 sri etc

What does these prefixes indicate?

Comment: Related [The story and Principle of adding “shree” “श्री” before our sacred religious books?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/13808/5212)

Comment: Which saint hv 108 Sri-s in front of his name?

Comment: @Rickross many of them

Comment: So for pronouncing such names people shd be carrying a Japamala with them..btw scriptures only ask to add only  one Sri and not those many.. @RakeshJoshi

Comment: @Rickross thats why they say and. Write like that... Its like battle of supremacy in many cases.. Such titles can be seen specially in pontiffs of mutts..