# Who conferred the " Śhrî Śhrî " honorific on the hindu âchârya, Ravi Shankar?

Tags: guru, name, title

Any information on who conferred the double honorific titular epithet (" Śhrî Śhrî ") on the hindu âchârya, Ravi Shankar? And on what basis?

Also, what are some other instances of people with the same Śhrî Śhrî  honorific?

Comment: Related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/29595/what-is-the-meaning-of-various-honorific-prefixes-with-sri

Comment: The marketing department.